# Django. Getting "ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111" when trying to send an email

Tags: python, django

### Description

I am trying to send an email using `django.core.mail.send_email()` and constantly getting the `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused` with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                               
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                          
  File "/home/EmilKadermetov/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 61, in send_mail                                                                          
    return mail.send()                                                                                                                                                                                           
  File "/home/EmilKadermetov/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send                                                                               
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])                                                                                                                                              
  File "/home/EmilKadermetov/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 102, in send_messages                                                                
    new_conn_created = self.open()                                                                                                                                                                               
  File "/home/EmilKadermetov/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 62, in open                                                                          
    self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)                                                                                                                           
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 253, in __init__                                                                                                                                                    
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)                                                                                                                                                                       
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 339, in connect                                                                                                                                                     
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)                                                                                                                                                       
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 308, in _get_socket                                                                                                                                                 
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,                                                                                                                                                       
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 807, in create_connection                                                                                                                                            
    raise err                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection                                                                                                                                            
    sock.connect(sa)                                                                                                                                                                                             
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

### My SMTP configurations in the `settings.py`:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOSTS = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_passwod'
```

### Additional

**"Less security app access"** in my google account is turned on.
I can successfully connect to the `smtp.gmail.com` via telnet from the same machine.
Using another smtp host changes nothing.

#### I use:

Django3.1.6 | Python 3.8.5 | Linux Mint 20.1

Comment: `can successfully connect to the smtp.gmail.com via telnet`: Using port 587? What does `nc smtp.gmail.com 587` say?

Comment: @Selcuk  yes: 
`telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying 74.125.205.109...
Connected to smtp.gmail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP w21sm2156470lfl.230 - gsmtp`

Comment: @Selcuk from nc: `220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP t17sm1611520ljk.34 - gsmtp`

Comment: That's weird. Django code does almost exactly the same thing. The "app security" setting should be irrelevant because you can't even establish the connection. Try writing a simple Python based socket client within the same virtualenv to see if it can connect.

Comment: Is the setting somehow being overwritten before that ```send_email``` line?  Can you post relevant parts of the code?

Comment: @ewong the lines from `settings.py` I posted are the last lines of the file - nothing can overwrite them. I call `send_email` from `manage.py shell` without any additional code before the call and after it and get the error anyway.

Comment: @Selcuk created a socket in the same `manage.py shell` where I am trying to use `send_mail()`,  got answer: `b'220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP z13sm3146021lji.115 - gsmtp\r\n'` . It is already driving me mad..

Comment: The only plausible explanation is the one suggested by @ewong . Try temporarily patching `/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py` to print the `host` and `port` values to the console.

Comment: Selcuk the host is `localhost` :D, because somebody (me, of course) put the line `EMAIL_HOSTS` instead of `EMAIL_HOST` in the `settings.py`. I deeply apologize for for troubling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a typo in the `settings.py` file's line which specify a SMTP host: `EMAIL_HOSTS = 'smtp.gmail.com'` instead of `EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'`. So Django used the default `EMAIL_HOST` parameter - `localhost` and was failing to connect. Thanks people in comments that tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

it helped me to add in settingd.py:

```
RECIPIENTS_EMAIL = ['manager@mysite.com']   # замените на свою почту
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'admin@mysite.com'  # замените на свою почту
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67579315/13170981